# How to turn off FireFox's responsive design's touch simulator

Tags: firefox

I noticed on my FF 26.0 that the responsive design view was upgraded to have a touch simulator. Now when I tried it I could not get it to dissable.

[image]

I tried togling it and leaving the responsive view and reloadig the page and even opening the page up in a new tab. Not even closing the browser and reopen the page gets rid of it the touch simulator, it is still on.

**EDIT :** I even tried to do a re-install, but no luck. It's still there.

Answer (score 1):

OK so after some searching on my own I found [this post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2784161) on the FF support forum. Were an analog problem ocured.

So this is how to solve this:
[image]

First : Go to *about:config* 
Second : Filter the settings to *dom.w3c* 
Third : Make sure that the settings are 0 and false (like in the pic).

It seams that when you (or at least when I) press the touch simulator, then the **dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled** is turned to 1 and is left like that.